# "AUTHENTICATION DISABLED", error using Firebase Ionic Email/Password Authentication

Tags: android, web-applications, ionic-framework, firebase

I followed the tutorial at https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-firebase-powered-end-end-ionic-application/ on integrating Firebase with Ionic App but I keep getting "AUTHENICATION DISABED" as the error returned.

I have enabled this particular option in the App dashboard from the Firebase Console but that is the error I get each time I try signing up or signing in.

Please what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Your tutorial use old version of firebase. You need some change to Android Firebase V2 when setup:

```
Go to your project dashboard. 
Find the Auth and click get started.
Go to set up sign in method and choose Email & Password and enable it.
```